# FuelCMS - How to find pages by id

Tags: php, fuelcms

Is there any way to find page by id in layout file. I'm currently using

`$this->fuel->pages->find(5)`

But its not working. I'm getting following error message

> Plugin module can not be found, maybe you forgot to bind it if it's a
>   custom plugin ?

Comment: Another dev on my team is experiencing the same thing, but I'm not. We're using a shared DB, he's running WAMP with PHP 5.4 and I'm running MAMP with PHP 5.5. Other than the Windows/Mac and PHP version everything should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an array to pass parameters in the method and you can use the `find_one`.

`$this->fuel->pages->find_one(array('where' => array('id' => 5)))`